# Magento : Get all Shipping Rates

Tags: magento

How can I get an array/object with the shipping rates in magento such as Flat Rate, Free Delivery etc ?

Irrelevant of the address or products selected.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way. You need to set a zip and country - even if that doesn't matter for your shipping methods.

```
// Change to your postcode / country.
$zipcode = '2000';
$country = 'AU';

// Update the cart's quote.
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$address->setCountryId($country)
        ->setPostcode($zipcode)
        ->setCollectShippingrates(true);
$cart->save();

// Find if our shipping has been included.
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                 ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
        print_r($rate->getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a note: the line "$cart->save();" is not necessary.

Comment: Does this post another request to shipping carriers based on the set $zipcode to get the rates?

Comment: @Silas Palmer , i have used your above code its working fine in After add to cart  product added...  But how i use your code before add to cart adding. Plz help me.

Answer (score 4):

you can't do it "irrelevant" as you need address data (billing or shipping if only billing then shipping set same as billing: country, zip, region dependant of your shipping methods) to be set and quote to have at least one simple item (quote existing, virtual and downloadable products don't need shipping). After that you can call on your quote object

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Comment: There's a small glitch in the code. Your variable is set with "()"

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out...

```
 $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
print_R($carrierConfig);
}
```

Thanks for the help