# Get Magento Shipping Quote/Rates List From External Code

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a bit of code that sits in a folder next to Magento. I'm pulling in `Mage.php` to do some stuff. I want to be able to grab some kind of shipping quote into my code. I have been looking around the web and I'm struggling to get anywhere sensible with it.

Please can someone show me the most efficient way to achieve this?

I only have this info available to pass in to get the rates:

```
Product ID eg, 123
Quantity eg, 1020
Country Code eg, GB
Zip code if needed eg, SY12 6AX
```

And I want to get out the following info:

```
Rate eg, £2.50
Title eg, Royal Mail Special Delivery
ID eg, 6
```

I want then to populate a radio list with the options on my code so that they can be selected.

Many thanks

Comment: If you have a product ID you could easily load any information connected to a product. What is your problem? Don't find the right models or do you have problems accessing/loading the data?

Comment: I'm not sure if i should be using Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart') or Mage::getModel('sales/quote') I have seen examples for both but dont see a way of passing in quantity.. sales/quote seems to be a very long winded way of doing it. I'm also looking for the most efficient way to do this as I have 20 sales staff on this all day firing customised quotes out to customers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I got it working. This is the final code to programmatically get a shipping quote from magento.

The function will return all available shipping rates for a particular product, quantity, country, postcode. The code excludes free shipping, this can be undone by removing `if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) { ...`

```
<?php
require_once("Mage.php");
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true); Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();


function getShippingEstimate($productId,$productQty,$countryId,$postcode ) {

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
    $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);

    $quote->addProduct($_product, $productQty);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($countryId)->setPostcode($postcode); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

    $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

    $shippingRates = array();
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate):
            if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                $shippingRates[] =  array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice());
            }
    endforeach;

    return $shippingRates;

}
echo "<pre>";
// product id, quantity, country, postcode
print_r(getShippingEstimate(1098,100,"GB","SY21 7NQ"));
echo "</pre>";
```

This could be put into a dropdown list like this:

```
$results = getShippingEstimate(1098,100000,"GB","SY21 7NQ");
$count = -1;
echo "<select>";
foreach ($results as $result):
$count++;
?>
<option value="<?=$count?>"><?=$result["Title"]." - £".$result["Price"]?></option>
<?php
endforeach;
echo "</select>"
```

Answer (score 3):

for shipping quote you need actual quote to be existing and essential address data (country, region, zip) populated to billing and shipping address and then you can ask rates:

```
$quote()->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

note that this is depending on shipping methods as well and on fact if they even allow you to give rates when quote is already calculated or about to be calculated

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I found this article which seems to work at getting the min amounts for each shipping rate based on country/zip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934138/magento-get-all-shipping-rates

which i think is what your talking about. I'm struggling to figure out how I can create a quote and use this to get the shipping rates without knowing any customer info apart from country.. It would be awesome if you could give me a full example. If not no worries, thanks for the input!