# Magento Free shipping for method with lowest rate

Tags: magento

Is it possible to dynamically specify the shipping method for Magento's free shipping module?

This is the logic I want to setup:

To US: Free shipping through UPS ground. 
To Canada: lowest rate from USPS or UPS APIs

I saw this post which provides a way to retrieve the cart's shipping methods: [Magento : Get all Shipping Rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934138/magento-get-all-shipping-rates)

```
$quote()->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

I was thinking finding a hook in the checkout process, finding the lowest quote, and adding it to the notes. I am concerned about changing the shipping method as it may affect the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a checkout observer which saved the lowest shipping method returned from the api to the order comments if the customer selects the free shipping method.